# Open File Dialog Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating an excel report in vb.net using the office interop. When the report is completed I am saving the excel file on the C drive. The users have asked to save file anywhere they want not just the c drive. Can someone give me some code to popup  an opend file dialog in asp.net?

I want the dialog to popup in a saveAs in ASP.NET. I know how to do it in win forms, but I am creating an excel report in asp.net and calling the worksheet objects SaveAs property that excepts a fileName. So right now I just hardcode a file name in there. The users want to choose a file location

Comment: Just to be clear... This is being done via ASP.NET, not WinForms?  And you're saving it to THEIR C: drive?

Comment: I think you're referring to .NET, not ASP.NET. ASP.NET is used only in a web context.

Comment: How are you currently saving it to the C Drive?

Comment: Dim fn as String="C:\RptCrd.xls"
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fn)

Comment: if you are trying to save it to C: on client side then isn't it throwing a security exception?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't saving out to the server C: not the client C:?

Comment: Is this a VBA (visual basic for Applications) script?

Comment: Yeah I wanted to save it on the client but maybe thats just a bad design. Its an intranet website app so I understand it makes no sense to download to a client but in my case it kinda does because the not all users can see the reports and managers dont want the reprots archived on the server.

Comment: Not vba, .net net app using excel interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is actually rather simple.

You can't save a file to the user's computer due to security restrictions (would you want a website saving a file to your computer?)

What you need to do is:

1. Complete report
2. Save report file to location **on server**, IE (.../myWebsite/files/GUID/myReport.rpt)
3. Display link on next screen pointing to the report file

Doing this the user can right-click and save the file to wherever they want on their computer.

You can clean up these files on whatever schedule you would like.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to save it on the client but maybe thats just a bad design. Its an intranet website app so I understand it makes no sense to download to a client but in my case it kinda does because the not all users can see the reports and managers dont want the reprots archived on the server.

Comment: I thought you might have some sort of privacy thing, which is why I used the GUID as a folder, this way you can't guess the path. You can also schedule a process that deletes all the folders in the "files" folder every night, this way the reports aren't archived.

Comment: they wanna have the other to create the file on the client and save it whereever they want on their machine. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are actually talking about a desktop, winforms app then you can use the built in FileSaveDialog.

Official documentation is here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx

but there are tons of tutorials explaining it out there:

- http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vb.net+savefiledialog

Comment: No I want the dialog to popup in a saveAs in asp.net. I know how to do it in win forms, but I am creating an excel report in asp.net and calling the worksheet objects SaveAs property that excepts a fileName. So right now I just hardcode a file name in there. The users want to choose a file location.

Answer (score 0):

You can server files with the Open / Save dialog by using `Response.TransmitFile()`.

The user is then presented with a save as dialog where they can choose the filename and the location on their computer.

You normally do this inside a `HttpHandler`. A simple one is described here:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/petel/archive/2005/12/01/499189.aspx

Comment: So there is no simple way to have for the user to choose a file location in asp.net?